# %s function Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function, kaggle

I want to build a function for following code:

```
PlayDirection_encoder = LabelEncoder()
train["PlayDirection"] = direction_encoder.fit_transform(train["PlayDirection"])
train.PlayDirection.unique()
```

That's my current function:

```
def object(category):
    %s = Label_Encoder() % (category + "_encoder")
    train[category] = %s.fit_transform(train[category]) %(category + "_encoder")
    len(train.category.unique())

object("PlayDirection")

UsageError: Line magic function `%s` not found.
```

I am running my code on Kaggle's server.
Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `%s` isn't a valid variable name.....

Answer (score 0):

1. calling function an `object` is really really bad idea. It's a reserved word in Python, so it might break everything in your code.
2. what do you want to achieve? your problem is not clear

Comment: I want to encode  a column in a pandas dataframe. Those are objects( ->strings) and I have to make numbers out of it.

Comment: @MarcoFurrer you could use `if` statements to switch between cases you need this and that encoders